# Probability that students got excellent at a random sample

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

From the freshmen we collect a random sample of $15$ students with a probability of $0.215$ one of them got excellent.

a) What is the probability that $4$ students have excellent?

b) What is the probability that only the eleventh got excellent?

c) If we know that out of a total of $20$ students, $8$ got excellent and we take a sample of $9$ out of $20$, then what is the probability that $2$ of the $9$ students got excellent?

$$$$

First we have to checkwhat distribution wehave, or not? Do we have binomial distribution?

If yes, do we have then the following ?

a) $P(X=4)=\binom{15}{4}\cdot 0.215^4\cdot (1-0.215)^{15-4}$

b) $P(\text{only the 11.th got excellent})=(1-0.215)^{10}\cdot 0.215\cdot (1-0.215)^{15-11}$

c) $P(\text{2 of the 9 students got excellent})=\binom{9}{2}\cdot \left (\frac{8}{20}\right )^2\cdot \left (1-\frac{8}{20}\right )^{9-2}$

Is everything correct?

Comment: The wording _with a probability of 0.215 one of them got excellent_ seems a bit confusing but considering it means probability that a student got excellent is $0.215$, your answers for $(a)$ and $(b)$ are correct.

Comment: For $(c)$, it should be ${8 \choose 2} {12 \choose 7} / {20 \choose 9}$ provided the meaning is _exactly_ two students. Favorable cases are where we choose $2$ from $8$ students who got Excellent and remaining $7$ from $12$ students who did not get Excellent.